# Is "easier than before" used in everyday English?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, american-english

I want to know if **"easier than before"** is correct in my sentence or not, and how I can say something makes things better than before. For example.

> "Our smartphones make learning languages easier than before."

Comment: Yes, it is correct. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: I am learning English through self-study, and sometimes I want to make sure if native speakers use this rule and that word to Improve my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Easier than before" gives the impression of an immediate improvement. There was a previous situation, and then you made a change, and now the situation is easier.

> I got a non-stick frying pan, so cleaning up is easier than before.

The sentence implies a specific change or event. Cleanup is easier than before I got the pan.

By contrast, your example sentence is not "everyday English" but advertising lingo. In that lingo, they usually prefer to say "easier than **ever** before".

> Our smartphones make learning languages easier than ever before!

Why do they do this? Because it makes their product the best yet, the latest in a chain of constant improvement... if it's easier than the previous product, it must also be the easiest ever. And why not use hyperbole to sell a product?

If a regular person says "easier than *ever* before", though, they'll sound like an ad. :)

Comment: What about "Smartphones make the process of learning languages easier than ever before."

Comment: @AbuOmar That would be fine too (in publicizing or perhaps encyclopedic lingo).

Comment: I wonder what the downvote is for; if someone's intuition conflicts with mine or they feel the explanation is inadequate, I hope they return to elaborate...